# How to get the current blog's ID

Tags: wordpress

I have a page name "Blog", it contains a list of posts.

In Settings->Reading->"Posts page:" I selected "Blog".

How can I get the id of the Blog from template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID of the page selected in Settings->Reading->"Posts page:" try this line of code:

```
$frontpost_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
```

Comment: That's great. If you found the answer useful, take a moment to accept this answer by clicking on the big checkbox on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you got to select "Blog" as the posts page it has to be a page you previously created in the Pages section.

To get the ID of the current page you simply do a $post->ID before you enter the loop of posts in your page template. First you do a `global $post` though. Like this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_id = $post->ID;
// Whatever else you're going to do
?>
```

Comment: I need to get blog's id from other pages.